# What guarantees are there on when GPIO states are read and written?

Tags: microcontroller, clock, gpio, trigger

I'm fairly new to electronics, coming from software engineering, and it's not clear to me when GPIO states are set or read in microcontrollers relative to a clock pulse.

If on cycle n, I toggle a GPIO, am I guaranteed to read the GPIO state change on cycle n+1, and never on cycle n, assuming the clock is shared ? Does that depend on the microcontroller used ? I'm mostly interested in the reliability, not in the latency, so, ignoring any GPIO read buffering or the likes.

For context, a practical example of that would be 2 PIOs of the RP2040 running, one side-setting a GPIO for triggering purposes while carrying its normal task, that pin being electrically wired to another GPIO, that the other PIO reads on every cycle to react to the trigger in a cycle-accurate fashion.

Comment: Usually GPIO takes many CPU cycles to change state (since cpus are typically much faster than pins), but this is device specific and the kind of thing you would look up in the device manual.

Comment: Did you look up the data sheet or other GPIO related documents of the MCU? Commonly these specify in detail, when a port pin as output changes its value, and when a port pin as input is read, in relation to the respective machine code operation.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the MCU.

For example, on an AVR, if you set an IO pin output state, you need to delay in software at least one clock cycle with a NOP before reading the pin status, to read back the updated current state.